# Register custom jmsserializer handler

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I need a custom JMSSerializer handler which handles forms differently and therefore created a class `AppBundle\FormJmsSerializerHandler`:

```
class FormJmsSerializerHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribingMethods()
    {
        return [
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form',
                'method' => 'process',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function process(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, Form $form, array $type)
    {
        return ['test' => 'success'];
    }

}
```

I register it in services.yml:

```
custom_jms_handler:
    class: AppBundle\FormJmsSerializerHandler
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }
```

Now JMS serializer's default form handler `jms_serializer.form_error_handler` has higher priority and therefore my custom handler is being ignored.

(EDIT) This was just a typo (This time PhpStorm refactoring failed):

<del>Now I get</del>

> <del>ReflectionException in CustomHandlersPass.php line 39:</del>
>   <del>Class AppBundle\FormJmsSerializerHandler does not exist</del>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you registered it like documented in JMS serialization doc: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers#subscribing-handlers

Comment: No. I'm using it together with FOSRestBundle. So I don't know where to do that. I want this handler to replace the default form handler for the whole application.

Comment: hm, but still you seem to use the JMS bundle for serialization, right? so check as well this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475801/custom-handler-on-jmsserializerbundle-is-ignored

Comment: yes, I use it for serialization. But FOSRestBundle invokes JMS serializer. So I don't have those `SerializerBuilder` etc. calls. I just return a Form object in my controller and FOSRestBundle converts it to JSON via JMS serializer.

Comment: i understand but i am pretty sure the solution for your problem is very much related. good luck!