# Doctrine2 , generate on a fly the value of a Entity's attribute that depends on symfony2 container

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an API, with an API call `GET /users` which returns me a list of users that all have a `avatar_url` field

in database this field is just the image name, and in the controller i'm then putting the base URL of my static domain serving images. So that it's only one URL to change in my conf , so the code works in staging/production etc.

but things start to get tricky with `GET /comments` etc. that all have sub-resource users that needs to have the url, so it means that currently every single point using users needs to have this logic, which is not very DRY

I would like to have something like that

```
// in my entity
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("url")
 */
public function getUrl()
{
    return $this->container->getParameter('IMG_URL').$this->imgName;
}
```

so that regardless on how deeply nested my entity is, I will be able to seralize it with the property.

It seems to me it is possible to achieve something like as there's a bundle

https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors

which seems to achieve something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers
From what I understand you could create your own handler for the url serializer. By having the handler as a service written by you, then you can inject anything you want in it.

More info can be found at [Creating a JMS Serializer handler in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240809/creating-a-jms-serializer-handler-in-symfony2)

Comment: interesting, I'm going to check that tomorrow, if it works I will check your answer.