# FosRestBundle: Dynamic VirtualProperties

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

In FOSRestBundle : Annotations, I want to use multiple [@VirtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) with dynamic names because i fetch the properties names from the database (unknown number of properties)

```
class User
{
   private $id;
   private $name;

   /**
    * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function getSomeMethod()
   {
       return array('property_name1'=> 'value1', 'property_name2'=>'value2');
   }
}
```

Where property_name1 & property_name2 .. property_name3 .. etc are dynamic with infinit number

I want to set them as virtual properties , each property has a string value.

I don't want to set them as array with one property.

If there is no way to do this, please let me know if i can do the same task from the controller?

Comment: You might be able to do this using `@Serializer\Inline` so that the properties of the array of bought up to be properties of the the parent object.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm!
Please post it in new answer to mark as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally a comment...

> You might be able to do this using `@Serializer\Inline` so that the properties of the array of bought up to be properties of the the parent object.

*Some more info*

This essentially allows you to have the exposed properties or keys/value of and array or object to be bought up to be properties of the parent object.

For example..

```
class Id
{
    /**
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;

    //...
}

class Parent
{
    /**
     * @Expose
     * @Inline
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Expose
     * @Inline
     */
    private $name = 'parent';

    /**
     * @Expose
     * @Inline
     */
    private [
        'key' => 'value',
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = new Id('an-id');
    }
}
```

Would first be transformed to an array similar to the following during serialization

```
[
    'id' => 'an-id',
    'name' => 'parent',
    'key' => 'value',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since FOSRestBundle uses JMSSerializer underneath and you want to be able to have full control of what the serializer returns and the output data strongly depend on the input it receives you can write a custom handler for one particular class.

For more detail info see:

- http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers
- http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration
- [Creating a JMS Serializer handler in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240809/creating-a-jms-serializer-handler-in-symfony2)