# How to serialize empty array to JSON object (curly braces) with JMS Serializer in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Having the following PHP class

```
class SampleObject 
{
    private $map;

    private $array;

    public function getMap(): array 
    {
        return $map;
    }

    public function setMap(array $map) 
    {
        $this->map = $map;
    }

    public function getArray(): array
    {
        return $this->array;
    }

    public function setArray(array $array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }
}
```

and two instances:

```
$inst1 = new SampleObject();
$inst2 = new SampleObject();
$inst1->setMap(['key' => 'value']);
$inst1->setArray([1]);
$inst2->setMap([]);
$inst2->setArray([]);
```

When they are serialized with JMS Serializer to json, the first one becomes:

```
{"map": {"key": "value"}, "array": [1]}
```

and the second one:

```
{"map": [], "array": []}
```

How to force the serializer to serialize the second object as `{"map": {}, "array": []}`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can override the default handler for arrays:
http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @EmanuelOster suggested in the comment, the [custom handler](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers) can be used for this purpose. While the solution is not perfect (an annotation on the field would be much better), it works. Here is a sample handler

```
class SampleObjectSerializer implements SubscribingHandlerInterface {
    public static function getSubscribingMethods() {
        return [
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => SampleObject::class,
                'method' => 'serialize',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function serialize(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, SampleObject $object, array $type, Context $context) {
        return [
            'array' => $object->getArray(),
            'map' => $this->emptyArrayAsObject($object->getMap()),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Forces to searialize empty array as json object (i.e. {} instead of []).
     * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41588574/878514
     */
    private function emptyArrayAsObject(array $array) {
        if (count($array) == 0) {
            return new \stdClass();
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

If using Symfony, you need to [register it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18240809/878514).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the array serialization behavior by setting context information on the `serialize` method (or using annotations etc.)

You'll find these examples about serializing arrays and hashes in the [cookbook](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/doc/cookbook/arrays.rst):

```
<?php

// default (let the PHP's json_encode function decide)
$serializer->serialize([1, 2]); //  [1, 2]
$serializer->serialize(['a', 'b']); //  ['a', 'b']
$serializer->serialize(['c' => 'd']); //  {"c" => "d"}

// same as default (let the PHP's json_encode function decide)
$serializer->serialize([1, 2], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array')); //  [1, 2]
$serializer->serialize([1 => 2], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array')); //  {"1": 2}
$serializer->serialize(['a', 'b'], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array')); //  ['a', 'b']
$serializer->serialize(['c' => 'd'], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array')); //  {"c" => "d"}

// typehint as strict array, keys will be always discarded
$serializer->serialize([], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<integer>')); //  []
$serializer->serialize([1, 2], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<integer>')); //  [1, 2]
$serializer->serialize(['a', 'b'], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<integer>')); //  ['a', 'b']
$serializer->serialize(['c' => 'd'], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<string>')); //  ["d"]

// typehint as hash, keys will be always considered
$serializer->serialize([], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<integer,integer>')); //  {}
$serializer->serialize([1, 2], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<integer,integer>')); //  {"0" : 1, "1" : 2}
$serializer->serialize(['a', 'b'], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<integer,integer>')); //  {"0" : "a", "1" : "b"}
$serializer->serialize(['c' => 'd'], SerializationContext::create()->setInitialType('array<string,string>')); //  {"d" : "d"}
```